# Is there a way to highlight the differences between two strings (textboxes)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a GUI using Python/Tkinter where I need to display the code from two files side-by-side and highlight the differences. While I can populate the code on a button-click, I am not able to figure out a way to highlight the differences in different color.

I tried *difflib.ndiff* and multiple similar approaches, but nothing seems to work as I need it to. Appreciate any help or suggestions in this regard.

```
txt_a.tag_config("bt1", font=("Georgia", "12", "bold"), background="red")
txt_b.tag_config("bt2", font=("Georgia", "12", "bold"), background="red")

op_list = [li for li in difflib.ndiff(a, b) if li[0] != ' ']
print(op_list)

for i in op_list:
    print(str(i))
    txt_a.tag_add("bt1", str(i), str(i+1))
    txt_b.tag_add("bt2", i, END)
```

I'm unable to get the desired output. Comparing multi-line strings a & b, getting the differences in op_list and need to highlight those (char's or lines) on the text widgets. Could you please help?

Comment: Are you asking how to highlight text in a text widget, or are you asking how to do the generate the diff in order to know what to highlight?

Comment: Hi Bryan, I'm able to find the character difference using _difflib.ndiff_. However, I want to highlight the lines having differences using a different color and I am unable to do that.

Comment: Do some research on tags in the text widget. For example, http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Bryan. I'll give it a try this weekend and will keep you posted.

Comment: Please don't put code in the comments. [edit] your question if you need to add additional information.

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley, thanks! Have updated the question. Appreciate your help.